# PHP foreach() define 2 things?

Tags: php

I'm trying to define both ['name'] and ['tmp_name'], but i'm having no idea how to do so?

Here is my code:

```
 foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $filename) {
   // Do stuff 
 }
```

But inorder to complete and move the file, I need the `$_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name']` aswell. How do I define both? I tried looking it up, but found nothing.

Comment: What does your array structure look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index from the foreach and access the associated entries:

```
foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $i => $filename) {

    $tmp_name = $_FILES["uploads"]["tmp_name"][$i];

}
```

Note: Do not use the unfiltered `name` for the target filename. That's a client-supplied value and can contain *anything*.